# Animate height to auto - storing height - slideUp with velocity.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, velocity.js

I'm trying to make a slide-toggle-fade animation like the `slideToggle()` method but with velocity.js - in the hopes that it will be much smoother.

Because I can't scroll to *auto* - I am putting the height in variable and using that to animate height. The issue I run into is that the height value is stored once and if the page is slightly resized, then the number is no longer correct. - Also - because the area is hidden on page load, (right after it gets the initial height) I can't check for height again (if window resize occurs)

Eventually I'd like to put it into a function, so keeping things relative it key.

Also, if you haven't used velocity.js, it's basically just like .animate() - so it's not really a part of the question.

### HTML

```
<section>
  <div class="button-w">
    <button>Toggle</button>
  </div>

  <div class="box">

    <p>{{content}}</p>

    <div class="button-w">
      <button>Close</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

### CSS

```
.button-w {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid lime;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
}
```

### jquery (velocity.js)

```
var boxxHeight = $('.box').outerHeight();

$('.box').hide();

$('button').on('click', function() {

    var boxx = $('.box');

    if ( boxx.is(":visible") ) {

      boxx.velocity({ opacity: 0, height: 0 }, { display: "none" });

    } else {

      boxx.velocity({ opacity: 1, height: boxxHeight }, { display: "block" });

    }

});
```

Any Ideas?

### EDIT

I didn't really have any real reason to need the sections to be `display: none`. This means that I can have an outer box with overflow: hidden, and the content will always have it's natural height to retrieve and work with.

```
<div class="button-w">
    <button>Toggle</button>
</div>

<div class="box">

    <div class="inner-wrapper">

    {{content}}

    <div class="button-w">
      <button>Close</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.box {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  .inner-wrapper {
    float: left;
    opacity: 0;
    padding-bottom: 5em;
    background: white;
    color: black;
    padding: 1rem;
  }
}

button {
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 0;
  &:focus {
    outline: 0;
  }
}

.hidden-box {
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 0;
  .inner-wrapper {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

### jQuery (with velocity.js)

"hide" the .inner-wrapper by setting the .box to height:0 and overflow hidden with .hidden-box class. The the height of the .inner-wrapper is stored and the height animation occurs just on the .box - and an opacity on the .inner-wrapper...

```
$('.box').addClass('hidden-box')

$('button').on('click', function() {

  var vBoxx = $(this).closest('section').find('.box');
  var vInner_wrapper = $(this).closest('section').find('.inner-wrapper');
  var vElementHeight = vInner_wrapper.outerHeight();

  if ( vBoxx.hasClass("hidden-box") ) {

    vBoxx.velocity({
      height: vElementHeight 
    }, {
      duration: 500,
    }).removeClass('hidden-box');

    setTimeout( function() {
      $(vInner_wrapper).velocity({opacity: 1});
    },250); 

  } else {

    $(vInner_wrapper).velocity({
      opacity: 0
    });

     setTimeout( function() {
      vBoxx.velocity({ height: 0 }).addClass('hidden-box');
    },250); 

  }

});
```

Working on [CodePen HERE:](http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/fmvLt/)

Comment: Find a way to fix your issue?

Comment: Almost, but not quite as handling all of the edge cases yet.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use `el.velocity("reverse");` to close it? The elements original height is already stored within Velocity.

Comment: Yeah. That is really cool. The think is, there are multiple buttons that do different things with the height... a close button and an open button that also acts as a close button etc... + If someone resizes their browser --- I want a  new height stored.

Comment: Worked perfectly for my use case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could try changing the `margin-top` value in order to move them up and down instead. It's not the best performance wise, but I think it's the only way you can do what you want correctly

```
var boxx = $('.innerbox'),
    count = 0;

$('button').on('click', function() {
    if(++count % 2 == 1) {
        boxx.velocity({ marginTop: "-100%" }, { duration:1000 });
    } else {
        boxx.velocity({ marginTop: "0%" }, { duration:1000 });
    }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/WnHB6/1/)

Comment: Pretty cool idea. It doesn't seem to work as expected though, when you have actual content in there. Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/WnHB6/   Your opacity suggestion made me wonder why I would really need to set the display property anyway.

Comment: @sheriffderek I updated my answer, having ignored your velocity calls the first time (whoops)

Comment: It doesn't perform as well as `transform`ing it would, but `transform` only changes the *visual* state, not the layout

Comment: Thought I was clever and was gonna get some SO karma for this one but you beat me to it by a few years. :P `marginTop: '-100%'` doesn't do it for me though, I need to get the `-outerHeight(true)` for it. http://codepen.io/corysimmons/pen/xZvPab?editors=1010

Answer (score 2):

You can now use

```
$element.velocity("slideUp", options);
$element.velocity("slideDown", options);
```

For instance

```
$element
    .velocity("slideDown", { duration: 1500 })
    .velocity("slideUp", { delay: 500, duration: 1500 });
```

It's worth noting that the height of the element is set to `auto` after the animation is completed. So no worries about containers with dynamic size ...

Official documentation: http://julian.com/research/velocity/#fade

Comment: Would be nice if you would provide more context and explanation.

Comment: @StephanKristyn Of course. I just added another example and a link to the corresponding section in the official documentation.

Comment: It still sets it to `display: none;` I think though.

Comment: @sheriffderek I'll check that but you could always wrap it inside a container if you don't want that behavior.